# Shellscript não encontra o diretório

Tags: ubuntu, shell, shell-script

estou começando com shellscript ,tenho que fazer a checksum de uns arquivos,então decidi automatizar as coisas com um script em bash..fiz dois scripts,um que usa um *ls* recursivo no diretório setado por mim e ignora pastas pegando apenas os arquivos*('d')* e passa numa variável de ambiente convertendo para uma string,a seguir um loop divide o output convertido em linhas,as quais são os paths dos arquivos,passando-os em outra variável de ambiente que é passada como parâmetro na chamada do segundo script,o qual recebe este argumento (path do arquivo),faz a checksum e passa td para um file.txt,a baixo os dois scripts:
primeiro script:

```
#/bin/bash                                                      ###TASK3###

arquivos=$(ls -R $1 | egrep -v '^d')

for linha in $arquivos
        do
                bash ./task2.sh $linha
        done
```

segundo script:

```
#/bin/bash                                              #####TASK2####



checksum=$(hashdeep $1)
concatenado=''

for i in $checksum
        do
                concatenado+=$i

        done

IFS=',' read -ra ADDR <<< "$concatenado"

echo
echo '----Checksum FILE:' $1
echo '----Checksum HASH:' ${ADDR[4]}
echo
echo ${ADDR[4]} >> ~/Trampo/shell_scripts/txt2.txt
```

O output(resumido pois sao muitos arquivos):

> /home/douglas/Trampo/shell_scripts/(cópia).png: No such file or
>   directory
>
> ----Checksum FILE: (cópia).png
>   ----Checksum HASH:

O erro é o seguinte: no caso aqui setei o diretório "~/Imagens", mas repare que no output ele retorna o caminho em que está meu script .sh com o nome do arquivo que está na pasta *~/Imagens*,só que não estou mandando ele para *~/Imagens* e não para */home/douglas/Trampo/shell_scripts/(cópia).png*,por exemplo,até por que o arquivo *cópia.png* não está nesse diretório mesmo...

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Grato!

---

Então amigo,eu tentei mudar os arquivos conforme tu me recomendou e outros links que vi net a fora...pórem sem sucesso,tentei duas coisas..

1º:

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -type f -exec ./task2.sh {} \;
```

2º:

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 ./task2.sh
```

tentei também:

```
find $1 -type f -exec bash ./task2.sh {} \;
```

este último funcionou parcialmente,o output dele ficou algo do tipo:

> ----Checksum FILE: /home/douglas/Imagens/Geotecnologia: tendências e desafios - Mozilla Firefox_003.png
>   ----Checksum HASH:
>
> ----Checksum FILE: /home/douglas/Imagens/Webcam/2016-10-27-001757.jpg
>   ----Checksum HASH: 40c760ff07c60b6a37d279ecdeab26b8
>
> ----Checksum FILE: /home/douglas/Imagens/2eVd0f1.jpg
>   ----Checksum HASH: bd52f7a0a3f8845d15218f6de0436808
>
> /home/douglas/Imagens/Captura: No such file or directory
>   /home/douglas/Trampo/shell_scripts/de: No such file or directory
>   /home/douglas/Trampo/shell_scripts/tela: No such file or directory
>   /home/douglas/Trampo/shell_scripts/de: No such file or directory
>   /home/douglas/Trampo/shell_scripts/2016-10-17: No such file or
>   directory /home/douglas/Trampo/shell_scripts/23-26-56.png: No such
>   file or directory

Comment: Oi! Esta conta é a mesma pessoa que a do autor da resposta/comentário em baixo?

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que no primeiro script `ls` retorna os caminhos **relativos** dos arquivos. Quando estes caminhos são consumidos no segundo script por `hashdeep`, o programa assume que eles são relativos ao diretório 'atual', que no caso seria o diretório dos scripts.

Proponho que ao invés usar `ls` no primeiro script use `find`, passando como parâmetro um caminho absoluto. Ex:

```
# find retorna caminhos absolutos quando o parâmetro é absoluto.
find ~/Imagens
```

Desta forma `find` irá retornar caminhos absolutos.

Obs.: Como caminhos absolutos serão passados para egrep, pode ser necessário alterar a expressão usada.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui corrigir o erro: apenas alterei a linha da 1º tentativa para:

```
find $1 -type f -exec **bash** ./task2.sh "{}" \;
```